# JQueryUI Accordion does not work for multi-level menus (items overlap)

Tags: html, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-accordion

I am using JQueryUI Accordion for creating a Vertical Multi-level Menu with the following code:

```
<ul class="accordion_menu">
  <li>
      <a href="#">Item 1</a>
  </li>
  <li>
      <a href="#">Item 2</a>
      <ul class="accordion_menu">
         <li><a href="#">Item 2 - 1 </a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Item 2 - 2</a>
             <ul class="accordion_menu">
                <li><a href="#">Item 2 - 2 - 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Item 2 - 2 - 2 </a></li>
             </ul>
         </li>
         <li><a href="#">Item 2 - 3 </a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Item 2 - 4</a></li>
      </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
      <a href="#">Item 3</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $(".accordion_menu").accordion({event: "mouseover", fillspace: true, collapsible: true});
    });
</script>
```

And, in this attached snapshot, you can see that there is overlap of elements.

[image]

Note:
If I remove "Item 1" then it all starts to work properly.
I am lost here. I am new to Jquery. Please guide me on what I could be missing..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was hard to search, just beacause I've use this plugin before, try to post it next time.

Here is an improved solution:

Script

```
$(function() {
    $(".accordion_menu").accordion({event: "mouseover", fillspace: true, collapsible: true});
    $('.accordion_submenu').hide();

$(".submenu").mouseover(function () {
    $('.accordion_submenu').slideDown("fast");
}).mouseout(function(){
$('.accordion_submenu').slideUp("fast");
  });
    });
```

HTML

```
<ul class="accordion_menu">
  <li>
      <a href="#">Item 1</a>
  </li>
  <li>
      <a href="#">Item 2</a>
      <ul class="accordion_menu">
         <li><a href="#">Item 2 - 1 </a></li>
     <li><a href="#" class="submenu">Item 2 - 2</a></li>
         <ul class="accordion_submenu">
                <li><a href="#">Item 2 - 2 - 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Item 2 - 2 - 2 </a></li>
         </ul>
         <li><a href="#">Item 2 - 3 </a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Item 2 - 4</a></li>
      </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
      <a href="#">Item 3</a>
 </li>
</ul>
```

Dirty, but it works.